# accessing entries in a list

Tags: python, arraylist, data-manipulation

I am trying to find optimal combinations (pairings) of players for a golf hobby project. I have as many as 40 players that need to be grouped into unique combinations of 4 players. The number of unique solutions is astronomical - something like 4^40th/10! (factorial). That is not a problem I can solve on a pc in a reasonable period of time

Instead I am using what I have been told is a greedy algorithm - I look for optimal results (pairs that have played the least previously) for the best twosome, throw away the higher scoring results, then re-pair the best twosome solutions with all of the twosome pairs, re-score and find the best solutions available. This approach results in a manageable number of possibilities. While I may miss the optimal solution, I will find very good answers.

When I use the combinations routine from itertools the first time I get answers in pairs in a list array `[(1,2),(3,4)...etc`. When I generate combinations from that list I get a result that looks like `[[((1, 2), (1, 3)), ((1, 2), (1, 4)), etc`. Since I need to eliminate duplicates (in the first item shown, player 1 appears twice) I need to be able to examine each component of the foursome (sorry if my terminology is off - self taught) and I don't know how to do that. So specifically, in the first entry in my list called `foursome_list`, how would I refer to each of the four positions (first entry = ((1,2),(1,3)) ). Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. Here is my sample code (proof of concept with only 8 players to keep the numbers down for now).

Thanks in advance

```
from itertools import combinations 

players  = [1,2,3,4]

pairs = combinations(players,2)

pairs_list = []
for i in list(pairs):
    pairs_list.append(i)

print("Pairs list =", pairs_list)

foursome = combinations(pairs_list,2)

foursome_list=[]
for i in list(foursome):
    foursome_list.append(i)

print ("Foursome list =", foursome_list)
print("length =", len(foursome_list))
print(foursome_list[0][0])
print(foursome_list[0][1])
```

Comment: What you want to achieve is not very clear. Could you please provide an example of what you would expect as a result from your input data?

Comment: Sorry - I need to be able to examine each of the four members of all of the members of foursome_list? For example - foursome_list [0] = ((1,2),(1,3). So how would i refer to each member -- the first 1 is referenced  as foursome_list [what?] The 2 is referenced how? The second 1 is referenced how? The 3 is referenced how?

Comment: `foursome_list[0][0][0]`, `foursome_list[0][0][1]`, `foursome_list[0][1][0]`, `foursome_list[0][1][1]`. you may want to use [list.extend](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) instead of `list.append` in order to obtain flatter data. you also could use `list(combinations(players, 2))` to avoid a loop for making a list from an iterator.

Comment: Thanks so much. It all works fine!